# ¿Cual es la diferencia entre Map y HashMap en JAVA?

Tags: java, map

Estoy realizando un Modelo de Vista en el que planeo recibir un JSONObject por medio de Web Services, el tema es que necesito recibir un objeto que es una lista de listas de datos, tengo una idea de como representar esto, creando una variable.

```
private Map<Integer,Map<Integer,Map>> MiListaDeListas;
```

Pero mientras investigaba di con la duda de HashMap , se que uno es una implementacion del otro, pero realmente no logre entender el concepto entre ellos.

Cual es la diferencia y en que casos es mejor usar uno del otro.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) es una interfaz que define el comportamiento general de una estructura que mantiene una relación de `key --> value`.

Luego, [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) es tan solo una implementación (aunque probablemente la más común) de un `Map` de entre varias que son posibles . Otras implementaciones de `Map` son por ejemplo `Hashtable`, `ConcurrentHashMap`, `WeakHashMap`, etc.  Cada una tiene sus ventajas y desventajas dependiendo de lo que estás tratando de hacer.

Cuando es posible, sobre todo si tu código es parte de una librería genérica de bajo nivel, es ventajoso definir el código usando la interfaz [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). Esto permite que el mismo código pueda usarse con cualquiera de sus implementaciones según el gusto del usuario.

Por ejemplo, si defines el método siguiente:

```
public void HacerAlgoConCualquierTipoDeMap(Map<int,String> tabla) {
  // ...
}
```

... entonces el mismo método puede ejecutarse sin problemas pasándole un `HashMap`, `Hashtable`, `ConcurrentHashMap`, `TreeMap` o cualquiera de las implementaciones de `Map`.

Pero si para el código que tienes es absolutamente necesario que el tipo de `Map` sea un `HashMap` (tal vez por razones de rendimiento o lo que fuera), entonces es correcto usar `HashMap` para impedir que se usen otras implementaciones en ese caso.

Comment: Creo que convendría resaltar las características principales de `HashMap`, en particular: 1) usa los métodos `equals` y `hashCode` para identificar la llave, 2) no mantiene un orden secuencial de los datos registrados.

Comment: Entonces la mejor manera de mantener este objeto como generico es con Map y si lo necesito castear a HashMap ? pudieras editar tu respuesta y profundizar un poco en sus diferencias.

Comment: Voy a tratar de ampliar un poco más...